# Problem in an internal loop with Set<Long>

Tags: java, for-loop, set

I'm having a trouble doing a `Set<Long>` loop. I have an `ArrayList<Long> values = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]` and a `Set<Long> values_set = [1,3,5,7]`.
I'm trying to do the following:

```
 for (Long value : values_set) {
   int valueId = value.intValue();
   for (int j = valueId+1; j < values_set.size(); j++) {
      Long res = values[j]
   }
 }
```

But in the second for, I get with the j different values to [1,3,5,7]. Does anyone know what I should do to go through the second loop?

Comment: can you describe in words what you're trying to do?

Comment: The second loop doesn't actually *do* anything, since it just gets values from the array and then lets them go out of scope. What are you trying to achieve? Could you perhaps show us some output that you would like to produce?

Comment: Can you describe what you want the variables to be after the loop? I'm having trouble understanding the problem here

Comment: Try a debugger or try it out on paper: value 1, j = 2, res = 2, ...

Comment: I want obtain this:  first:  value = 1; j = 3 res= 3 second: value = 3, j=5 res = 5 three: value= 5, j=7 res= 7

Answer (score 0):

It seems a couple of iterators should be used here instead of `for-each` loop to go through the set of indexes and to pick up a pair of indexes: `1 and 3`, `3 and 5`, `5 and 7`.

The inner loop seems to be quite redundant then, that is, some value should be retrieved from the list at the index following the current one.

Also, naming of the variables needs to be improved because `values/values_set/valueId` are not very descriptive.

```java
List<Long> arr = Arrays.asList(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L); // values
Set<Long> indexes = new TreeSet<>(Set.of(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L)); // values_set

Iterator<Long> itTo = indexes.iterator();
itTo.next(); // skip the first element

for (Iterator<Long> itFrom = indexes.iterator(); itTo.hasNext(); ) {
    Long from = itFrom.next(); // valueId
    Long to  = itTo.next();    // j
    Long res = arr.get(to.intValue());  // res
    
    System.out.printf("from: %d,\tto: %d,\tres: %d%n", from, to, res);
}
```

Output:

```
from: 1,    to: 3,  res: 3
from: 3,    to: 5,  res: 5
from: 5,    to: 7,  res: 7
```